# Is it possible to get more than three suggested routes in Google Maps?

Tags: google, google-maps

Can one get more than 3 suggested routes via Google Maps?

If so, how?

Comment: maybe describing why you will need more than 3 suggested routes will help users understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @phwd - Nothing amazing really, I simply wan't more than 3 options home from work.

Comment: It depends on your mode of transport. With public transportation I usually get 5 suggested routes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that way, according to this [unofficial blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-maps-shows-suggested-routes.html) about the feature, which only mentions 3 suggested routes.

However, there is one method of getting a few more alternate routes, by using the **Avoid highways** or **Avoid tolls** options, which are visible when you click on **Show options**. [More info about this feature](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24867).

I've noticed that if you have more than two points, it won't offer alternative suggested routes, so make sure you only have two points defined. Similarly, you should avoid dragging the route, as it also removes any suggested routes.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the blue line route you can then drag a point on it to somewhere else, effectively changing the route.

Comment: Im looking for more suggested routes, otherwise I may as well plot my own one.

Comment: Suit yourself, but being able to drag and change routes is one of the most useful aspects of Google maps directions, IMO. It's nothing like equivalent to plotting your own one.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, since it looks like you can't quite do this in Google Maps automatically:

I would try breaking the route into two or three parts (depending on length), and then changing the intermediate point(s) a little bit. See what suggestions you get on the partial routes.

You can combine them into one route when you're done, but unfortunately, you'd need to do all this manually.

Another idea is to play with the different modes: Driving, walking, and cycling will often give you very different routing suggestions.